# Is there a way to change the capitalization in modelsummary for fixed effects without renaming the columns?

Tags: r, modelsummary

I want to have my fixed effects capitalized in the `modelsummary` output. While I know I could rename the columns before estimating the regression, I wanted to know if there is an easier way to do this within the `modelsummary::modelsummary` function. I have tried the `coef_map` argument, but it doesn't seem to affect the table.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(modelsummary)
library(fixest)

mtcars %>% 
  feols(mpg ~hp | gear, data = .) %>% 
  modelsummary(stars = T, coef_map = c("hp" = "Horsepower",
                                       "mpg" = 'MPG',
                                       "gear" = "Gear"))
```

As shown in the example, I want the "gear" fixed effect to be capitalized without having to rename in my data (if possible).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `modelsummary` table is essentially composed of two parts. The top contains estimates and is controlled by the `coef_*` arguments. The bottom contains “goodness-of-fit” and other model characteristics, and is controlled by the `gof_*` arguments.

You can rename and reformat and reorder the GOF info with the `gof_map` argument. In this example, I use the `tribble` function to create a `data.frame` with the information needed to rename and capitalize. You can also use a list, or a plain `data.frame`. Please refer to the documentation.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(modelsummary)
library(fixest)

gm <- tribble(~raw, ~clean, ~fmt,
              "FE: gear", "FE: Gear", ~fmt)
mtcars %>% 
  feols(mpg ~hp | gear, data = .) %>% 
  modelsummary(output = "markdown",
               stars = T, coef_map = c("hp" = "Horsepower",
                                       "mpg" = 'MPG',
                                       "gear" = "Gear"),
               gof_map = gm)
```

|  | Model 1 |
| --- | --- |
| Horsepower | -0.067* |
|  | (0.016) |
| FE: Gear | X |

**Note:**
^^ + p < 0.1, * p < 0.05, ** p < 0.01, *** p < 0.001

Comment: One thing I notice when I use this method is that the "goodness-of-fit" statistics disappear unless specified inside of the `gof_map` `data.frame` that I pass in. While this is generally not a problem, and is actually a nice feature, I can't seem to find how the "Std.Errors" is mapped. For instance, if I were cluster in the above example and run your code, the "Std.Errors" output from the table would be deleted. When I try and map "Std.Errors" in the `tribble` function, it doesn't seem to work. I looked in the documentation and couldn't seem to figure out how this is mapped.

Comment: Good catch! This will require a fix to the package. We are planning to work on this part of the code in the near future, and I opened an issue to make sure this issue gets addressed. I can't give you a specific timeline, but this shouldn't take too long to fix. In the meantime, the best you can probably do is add a row manually with `add_rows`. Thanks for the bug report!

Comment: Link to the issue if you want to follow progress: https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/modelsummary/issues/384

Comment: Is this issue already fixed? The github post was closed but without an apparent fix?

Comment: @Anton I left an example in the github issue linked above. Feel free to comment there if this does not meet your needs.